# How can I make `history` in OS X keep a longer list of last commands?

Tags: macos, command-line

I love using `history` from the command line to keep track of commands but I find its list to be a bit too short for my liking.  Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 10):

In your `~/.bash_profile` file, export the HISTSIZE variable to the desirable number of entries to save:

```
export HISTSIZE=5000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the size of the `history` buffer by typing `set history=100`. If you put this in your `~/.bashrc` then it will remain permanent.

Comment: here is no `.bashrc` on OS X by default. I suggest `.bash_profile` instead.